# Is the universal enveloping algebra of a finite-dimensional Lie algebra (left) noetherian? 

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, rt.representation-theory

The universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is a flat deformation of $S(\mathfrak{g})$, so these algebras should be similar in many ways. Does at least this general similarity hold?

Comment: The universal enveloping algebra of a finite dimensional Lie algebra is a so-called G-alegbra, hence is left and right Noetherian (see e.g. http://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/3-1-5/sing_510.htm). Note that this includes quantized enveloping algebra as well.

Comment: Adrien, thank you very much for the reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, if a filtered ring $R$ has the property that its associated graded ring is Noetherian, then $R$ is Noetherian.  Universal enveloping algebras have a PBW filtration such that the associated graded algebra is $S(\mathfrak{g})$. This is proved in Noncommutative Noetherian Rings by McConnell,  Robson,  Small - see sections 1.6 and 1.7.

Comment: You're welcome - do you have a reference for the flat deformation idea you mentioned in the question? It seems like an interesting point of view.

Comment: I don't have a reference, but I can just explain you how I see it. $U(g)$ is the quotient of the tensor algebra $T(g)$ modulo the relations $x\otimes y−y\otimes x−[x,y]$ for $x,y\in g$. Let $k$ be the base field, $t$ be a variable and $B$ be the quotient of the algebra $T(g)\otimes_k k[t]$ modulo the relations $x\otimes y−y\otimes x−t[x,y]$. Then $B$ is (I hope --- I haven't checked) a free $k[t]$-module with the usual PBW basis and an algebra over $k[t]$, the fiber of $B$ over the point $t=0$ is $S(g)$, and the fiber over $t−a$ for $a\in k^*$ is $U(g)$.

Comment: I think I got the idea of the construction from Chapter 6 of Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra with a View toward Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: And here is more to deformation: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/41142/geometric-interpretation-of-universal-enveloping-algebras