# Filtrations and Koszul algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, graded-rings-modules, koszul-algebras, associated-graded, filtered-algebras

I was looking at this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429814/properties-of-a-filtered-algebra-that-can-be-concluded-from-properties-of-its-as) and asked my self the following:

> Let $A$ be graded algebra, which is also an $\mathbb{N}_0$-filtered algebra. If its associated
> graded algebra $\mathrm{gr}(A)$ is Koszul does that imply that $A$ is
> also Koszul?

Is this true for some suitable assumptions on the compatibility of the grading and the filtration?

Comment: What definition of Koszul do you want to use for such $A$? The usual definition requires that the algebra be graded...

Comment: Yes $A$ should be graded. I have now added this to the question.

Comment: Is there any relation between the grading and the filtration of $A$? Is it the canonical filtration associated to the grading?

Comment: @M.G. I am interested in the case where it is a different filtration.